# Block time slot in calendar if it's closer than 24 hours

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar, blocking, appointment

I am building a website for a service providing website, and I have a calendar for the appointment booking form. I need to block all time slots that are closer than the next 24 hours.
My understanding is that I have to check the current date and time, and compare it to the date and time the user input in the calendar.

I am relatively new to PHP, but I have been testing a little bit, to see if I can figure it out by myself. So far, I have checked for the current date, and tested with a different date to see if it works (it does). Now, I am unsure about how to pull the input date into the code.

```
<?php
$date1=date_create(date('m/d/Y h:i:s A'));
$date2=date_create($_REQUEST['appointment_date']);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
?>
```

I though this should work, but of course, if would have to pull the input date real time, and I don't know if there is a way to do that.
Ideally, I would like to block the timeslots that are less than 24 hours away.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're having trouble with. What do you mean by _"have to pull the input date real time"_?

Comment: Well, it should respond real time, but when I fill the form in, it doesn't respond. (that's why I have it print out the result, for testing).

Comment: Respond with what? How is this form submitted, regularly or through AJAX? I still don't understand what's troubling you.

Comment: As of right now, it should echo out the result. The form was not build with AJAX. I think I am lost... sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: So when you try to run it, what happens instead?

Comment: It echoes "+0days"

Comment: Alright, are the days you have supplied less than a day apart? Providing sample input, current output and desired output would help a lot towards explaining what goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. The code I have, to my understanding, should tell me how many days there are between the current date and the selected date. What I need is for the dates and time slots that are less than 24 hours away from the current date, to be blocked. That is the ideal eventual outcome. So far, what I have is just the code that checks for the current date, and how many days that is away from the chosen date. Currently it outputs "+0days"

Comment: But now that I think about it, I realize that it states that regardless, which makes me think I probably didn't map the chosen field properly.

Comment: Okay, your first step is correctly initializing the date objects. Once you take care of that, the difference should be calculated correctly. Then you should probably wrap that in a function which you can use to return a value. Based on the returned value, you can validate your form in whatever way you wish.

Comment: I will work on that and update this later. Thank you very much for your time thus far.